# Minimum number of states in dfa accepting binary number with decimal equivalent divisible by $n$

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I was aware of the fact that, if DFA needs to accept binary string with its decimal equivalent divisible by $n$, then it can have minimum $n$ states.

However recently came across following text:

> - **If $n$ is power of $2$**
>     Let $n=2^m$, so number of minimum states $=m+1$.
>     For $n=8=2^3$, we need $3+1=4$ states.
> - **Else If $n$ is odd**
>     Number of states $=n$.
>     For $n=5$, we need $5$ states.
> - **Else if $n$ is even**
>     Keep dividing it with $2$ until you get odd quotient. The result is final odd quotient plus number of divisions done.
>     For $n=20,20/2=10,10/2=5→5+2=7$ states

I was guessing:
**Q1.** From where all these facts came. (I know this must have come from general pattern that such DFAs follow, but then I have below doubts)
**Q2.** Are these points indeed correct?
**Q3.** If yes (for Q2), then what can be the reason for each point?
**Q4.** Do these three bullet points cover all cases? (I guess yes, since there is even and odd, but I am new to this, and I was guessing if any such more point is left unmentioned in my textbook, especially since I did not find any reference book (by Peter Linz and Hopcroft-Ullman) talking about this topic)

Comment: There are a few things missing here. First, is the number input LSB to MSB or MSB to LSB? (Looks like LSB to MSB.) Second, are you allowing the empty string to represent zero?

Comment: The way to prove such results is to twofold: first you prove an *upper bound* by constructing a DFA accepting the given language, then you prove a *lower bound* using Myhill–Nerode theory.

Comment: For an example, see this: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85785/minimum-number-of-states-in-the-dfa/85803#85803.

Comment: Regarding Q4, yes, they cover all cases. I'm certain you can prove this in your own, even if you're new to "this" – this has nothing to do with automata theory.

Comment: Can you provide any link discussing these two points: (1) LSB to MSB and MSB to LSB number input (2) Representing zero by empty string and possibly these two points in the context of "divisible by $n$ DFA" . Also I guess first point wont make number of states in min DFA to change. Second point might change it.

Comment: The distinction between LSB to MSB and MSB to LSB is just the order in which the digits of the binary string are arranged. That is, if my input is the binary representation of 16, should I get 10000 (reading from most significant to least significant bit) or 00001 (least significant to most significant)? The answer I wrote below assumes the input is given MSB to LSB, though you can [convert such a DFA into one for LSB to MSB](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1023316). I'm curious if the bounds are the same for non-powers of 2 for a LSB to MSB input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Case 1: $n$ is a power of 2

If you wanted to check whether a decimal number is divisible by some power of 10,  you can just look at the number of trailing zeros. For example, all numbers that are divisible by $100 = 10^2$ end with 2 zeros (this is of course including numbers ending with more than 2 zeros). The same idea can be applied here for binary numbers and powers of 2. Specifically to check for multiples of $n = 2^m$, you can simply check if the string ends in $m$ zeros. For example, if $n = 16 = 2^4$, all multiples of $n$ will end in 0000 (4 zeros). Thus we can create the following DFA for $n = 16$:

[image]

This construction can be extended to all multiples of 2, where you have $m+1$ states to ensure that your input ends in at least $m$ zeros (reading a 0 takes you one state forward, reading a 1 takes you back to the start). As suggested in the comments on your question, you can show that you can't do any better than this using a Myhill–Nerode argument.

### Case 2: $n$ is odd

The general idea here is that when a number is divided by $n$, the possible remainders are $0, 1, \ldots, n-2$ or $n-1$. We can give our DFA one state for each of these possible remainders so as we process a string, we're keeping track of the remainder of what we've read so far and transitioning to the appropriate remainder based on what character we read. Then, we accept if we finish in the remainder 0 state.

[Design DFA accepting binary strings divisible by a number 'n'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22282792/9119977) walks through a detailed method for constructing such a DFA, and you can find out more about this by searching for "DFA based division". This gives a total of $n$ states, which is optimal by Myhill-Nerode because these remainders are exactly the equivalence classes given by the relation $\equiv_L$ for the language $L = \{\text{binary strings divisible by }n\}$.

### Case 3: $n$ is even (and not a power of 2)

The technique in case 2 also works here but it isn't optimal. Every $n$ in this case can be expressed as $2^km$ where $m$ is odd (this is the division procedure described in your question). Thus, to check whether a binary string is divisible by $n$, we check whether it is divisible by both $2^k$ and $m$.

We know that it takes $k$ states to check divisibility by $2^k$ (case 1) and $m+1$ states to check divisibility by $m$ (case 2). We can take a DFA for divisibility by $m$, unmark the accepting state and make it the start state for a DFA for divisibility by $2^k$, giving our final DFA $k+m$ states.

As an example, here's the DFA for $n = 6$:

[image]

The top three states ensure that the number is a multiple of 3, and the final accept state ensures that it is a multiple of 2.

Comment: Revisiting this problem, I dont get how to combine two DFAs in case 3. You said "unmark the accepting state and make it the start state for a DFA for divisibility by $2^k$". But you didnt explain how you came up with transition outgoing (labeled 1) from final state of last DFA. If we are to combine "divisible by $2^k$ DFA" with "divisible by $m$ ($m$ being any odd number)" DFA, "all" outgoing transitions on reading "1" from "all" states of divisible by $2^k$ DFA will go to same second state of divisible by $m$ DFA, (**Q1.**) right? [to next comment...]

Comment: [..from earlier comment] For divisible by $2^k$, we need string to end with $k$ zeroes. But, your case 3, divisible by 6 DFA will also let $k=1$ zeroes appear anywhere. (**Q2.**) How this fits in divisible by 6 string? For example in your divisible by 6 DFA, for 110110, first 11 moves through divisible by 3 DFA, next 01 moves through divisible by 2 DFA, next 1 moves through divisible by 3 DFA and final 0 moves through divisible by 2 DFA. (**Q3.**) How running through different component DFAs one after other still ensures that the whole string will still be divisible by $2^km$